# templates in factory pattern

Tags: c++

When I was explaining a factory pattern which takes in a enum to its createobject static method, a colleague asked how can we make it such that we dont have to add a switch case every time we have a new derived class defined. Something on the below lines. I know it wont compile(just to put the idea better)

```
template <class T>
class theCreator {
  public:
    static T* createInstance(int a_ichoice) {
      return new T();
    }
};

class theBase {
  public:
    virtual void SayyourName() = 0;
};

class theDerived1 : theBase {
  public:
    void SayyourName() {
      cout << typeid(this).name();
    }
};

class theDerived2 : theBase {
  public:
    void SayyourName() {
      cout << typeid(this).name();
    }
};

int main() {
  theBase * p = theCreator::createInstance(1);
  p->SayyourName();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with a templated `static theBase* createInstance`?

Comment: Without a `switch`, how do you do anything useful with `a_ichoice`?  A factory is for selecting a type at run time; how can it know what template types to instantiate at compile time?

Comment: @aschepler: I wanted to know if there is any generic implementation to this which would get rid of this housekeeping with a switch?

Comment: @aschepler easy: take a list of types, and instantiate `template` code for each of them, then pick between which of the types you are using.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can associate a list of types with an index into said list at run time.  Not sure if you really want to.  Here is an example of me taking a type, mapping it to an index into a list of types, calling a virtual function, then reversing the mapping back to a type, and calling a template function in the implementation based off of the original type passed in:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Types>
struct TypeList {};

template<typename T, typename List, typename=void>
struct IndexOf;

template<typename T, typename First, typename... Types>
struct IndexOf<T, TypeList<First, Types...>,
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same< T, First >::value
  >::type
> {
  enum {value = 0};
};

template<typename T, typename First, typename... Types>
struct IndexOf<T, TypeList<First, Types...>,
  typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_same< T, First >::value
  >::type
> {
  enum {value = 1+IndexOf<T, TypeList<Types...>>::value};
};

template<size_t n, typename List>
struct TypeAt;

template<size_t n, typename First, typename... Types>
struct TypeAt<n, TypeList<First, Types...>> {
    typedef typename TypeAt<n-1, TypeList<Types...>>::type type;
};

template<typename First, typename... Types>
struct TypeAt<0, TypeList<First, Types...>> {
    typedef First type;
};

template<typename Functor, typename List>
struct TypeDispatch {
    struct Helper {
        Helper( Functor const& f_ ):f(f_) {}
        Functor const& f;
        template<size_t n>
        void Call() const {
            typedef typename TypeAt<n, List>::type target_type;
            f.template Call<target_type>();
        }
    };
};

template<size_t max>
struct RuntimeSwitch {
    template<typename Functor>
    static bool Call( size_t n, Functor const& f ) {
        if (n == max) {
            f.template Call<max>();
            return true;
        } else {
            return RuntimeSwitch<max-1>::template Call( n, f );
        }
    }
};

template<>
struct RuntimeSwitch< size_t(-1) > {
    template<typename Functor>
    static bool Call( size_t n, Functor const& f ) {
        return false;
    }
};

template<typename List>
struct DynamicTypeDispatch;

template<typename... Types>
struct DynamicTypeDispatch<TypeList<Types...>> {
    template<typename Functor>
    static bool Call( size_t n, Functor const& f ) {
        typedef TypeDispatch<Functor, TypeList<Types...>> typeDispatch;
        typedef typename typeDispatch::Helper typeCaller;
        return RuntimeSwitch<sizeof...(Types)-1>::Call(n, typeCaller(f));
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct Test {
    std::string s;
    Test( std::string s_ ):s(s_) {}
    template<typename T>
    void Call() const {
        std::cout << sizeof(T) << " == " << s.c_str() << " I hope\n";
    }
};

struct Test2Base {
    typedef TypeList<int, double, char> TestList;
    virtual void Dispatch( size_t n ) = 0;
    template<typename T>
    void Test(T const& unused) {
        Dispatch( IndexOf<T, TestList>::value );
    }
};
template<typename Child>
struct Test2CRTP: Test2Base {
    Child* self() { return static_cast<Child*>(this);}
    Child const* self() const { return static_cast<Child const*>(this); }

    template<typename T>
    void Call() const {
        self()->template TestImpl<T>();
    }
    virtual void Dispatch( size_t n ) {
        DynamicTypeDispatch<Test2Base::TestList>::Call( n, *this );
    }
};
struct Test2Impl: Test2CRTP<Test2Impl> {
  template<typename T>
  void TestImpl() const {
      std::cout << T(256.1) << "\n";
  }
};
int main()
{
    typedef TypeList<int, double> TestList;
    DynamicTypeDispatch<TestList>::Call( 0, Test("4") );
    DynamicTypeDispatch<TestList>::Call( 1, Test("8") );

    Test2Impl test2;
    test2.Test(int());
    test2.Test(char());
    test2.Test(double());
}
```

Now, do you really want to do something this heavy weight, rather than maintain an `enum`?

But it is possible.  :)